# What is the equivalent of Reduce for a list in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list, `mylist` with 5 elements.

I can merge any two elements using the following:

```
merge(mylist[[1]], mylist[[2]], by = someColumn).
```

However, how do I merge all of them together at once while preserving the names and not causing warnings.

Thanks!

**Edit**

Upon further inspection, here's a few more details to help clarify my question:

```
> mylist
$Alpha
   id count
1 ABC     5
2 DEF    10
3 GHI    15

$Beta
   id count
1 DEF    10
2 ABC    12
3 GHI    14

$Gamma
   id count
1 ABC    13
2 GHI    15
3 DEF    17

$Kappa
   id count
1 GHI    20
2 DEF    21
3 ABC    25
> Reduce(function(x,y){merge(x,y,by="id")}, mylist)
   id count.x count.y count.x count.y
1 ABC       5      12      13      25
2 DEF      10      10      17      21
3 GHI      15      14      15      20
Warning message:
In merge.data.frame(x, y, by = "id") :
  column names ‘count.x’, ‘count.y’ are duplicated in the result
```

As you can see, things are repeated at the top of the result and R throws a warning. How can I get it to avoid that (preferably calling the column names by the same as the list names -- so the first count.x would be count.Alpha).

Here's a copy of `mylist` in dput form in case anyone wants it:

```
structure(list(Alpha = structure(list(id = structure(1:3, .Label = c("ABC", 
"DEF", "GHI"), class = "factor"), count = c(5, 10, 15)), .Names = c("id", 
"count"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"), Beta = structure(list(
    id = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"
    ), class = "factor"), count = c(10, 12, 14)), .Names = c("id", 
"count"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"), Gamma = structure(list(
    id = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"
    ), class = "factor"), count = c(13, 15, 17)), .Names = c("id", 
"count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), Kappa = structure(list(
    id = c("GHI", "DEF", "ABC"), count = c(20, 21, 25)), .Names = c("id", 
"count"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("Alpha", 
"Beta", "Gamma", "Kappa"))
```

Comment: `Reduce()` works just fine on a list. What exactly is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: @MrFlick: you're right, I've expanded on my problem with more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just run a quick `Map` to rename the "count" column. For example

```
Reduce(merge, Map(function(n,x) {names(x)[2]<-n; x}, names(mylist), mylist))
```

this returns

```
   id Alpha Beta Gamma Kappa
1 ABC     5   12    13    25
2 DEF    10   10    17    21
3 GHI    15   14    15    20
```

Comment: can you explain how the Map works a bit more here? When I just copy and paste the Map portion, I get back my original list...

Comment: @user1357015 If you carefully check, you will see that the column name `count` have been replaced by `Alpha`, `Beta` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `match.call()`:

```
 Reduce(merge, lapply(mylist, function(x) {
                   names(x)[2] <- paste(names(x)[2], names(mylist)[match.call()[[2]][[3]]],sep=".")
                 x}))
#   id count.Alpha count.Beta count.Gamma count.Kappa
#1 ABC           5         12          13          25
#2 DEF          10         10          17          21
#3 GHI          15         14          15          20
```